# Reverse a comma separated column that stores hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a query that creates a H_TREE column from the below TABLE,

```
+------+--------+
| UNIT | M_UNIT |
+------+--------+
|   10 |     12 |
|   15 |     19 |
|   12 |     16 |
|   13 |     15 |
|   19 |     14 |
|   14 |     11 |
+------+--------+
```

Following is the query I am using,

```
WITH data (unit, m_unit) AS (
  SELECT 10, 12 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 19 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 16 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 15 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 19, 14 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 11 FROM dual)
SELECT
    unit,
    m_unit,
    unit || ',' || listagg(root_unit, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth) h_tree
FROM (
SELECT
    id, unit, m_unit,
    LEVEL depth, CONNECT_BY_ROOT m_unit root_unit
FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUM id, unit, m_unit FROM data) data
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR unit = m_unit)
GROUP BY
    id,
    unit,
    m_unit
```

The above query returns,

```
+------+--------+----------------+
| UNIT | M_UNIT |     H_TREE     |
+------+--------+----------------+
|   10 |     12 | 10,12,16       |
|   15 |     19 | 15,19,14,11    |
|   12 |     16 | 12,16          |
|   13 |     15 | 13,15,19,14,11 |
|   19 |     14 | 19,14,11       |
|   14 |     11 | 14,11          |
+------+--------+----------------+
```

I want to reverse the order of H_TREE column so that it comes out as below,

```
+------+--------+----------------+
| UNIT | M_UNIT |     H_TREE     |
+------+--------+----------------+
|   10 |     12 | 16,12,10       |
|   15 |     19 | 11,14,19,15    |
|   12 |     16 | 16,12          |
|   13 |     15 | 11,14,19,15,13 |
|   19 |     14 | 11,14,19       |
|   14 |     11 | 11,14          |
+------+--------+----------------+
```

### What changes do I need to make to this existing query in order to achieve this?

As per comments: WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth DESC) gives me the following result,

```
+------+--------+----------------+
| UNIT | M_UNIT |     H_TREE     |
+------+--------+----------------+
| 10   |  12    |  10,16,12      |
| 15   |  19    |  15,11,14,19   |
| 12   |  16    |  12,16         |
| 13   |  15    |  13,11,14,19,15|
| 19   |  14    |  19,11,14      |
| 14   |  11    |  14,11         |
+------+--------+----------------+
```

Comment: `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth DESC)` add DESC here

Comment: This does not return the order I mentioned in my query. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what "WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth DESC) " gives you as a result?

Comment: I have added the result in my question thanks @haytem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH data (unit, m_unit) AS (
    SELECT 10, 12 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 15, 19 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 16 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 13, 15 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 19, 14 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 14, 11 FROM dual)
SELECT
    unit,
    m_unit,
    listagg(root_unit, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY depth desc) || ',' || unit as h_tree
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, unit, m_unit,
        LEVEL depth, CONNECT_BY_ROOT m_unit root_unit
    FROM
        (SELECT ROWNUM id, unit, m_unit FROM data) data
    CONNECT BY
        PRIOR unit = m_unit)
GROUP BY
    id,
    unit,
    m_unit
```

Comment: This query throws: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 5

Comment: Thank you @Haytem it works perfectly. Appreciate your help.